# Not able to start DSE-5.0 cassandra. Getting Bind Exception on Solr port

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

While running `bin/dse cassandra` for `DSE-5.0.5` on mac, I am getting below error. The `solr` is not able to start and I changed the `catalina port` from `8983` to `8993`. But I am still getting the error on the new port too.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
INFO: Initialization processed in 432 ms
INFO  19:52:41,078  TomcatSolrRunner.java:144 - server.xml has no connectors so creating a default http connector to run the Solr web application.
Jan 30, 2017 7:52:41 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
SEVERE: Error initializing endpoint
java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address (Bind failed) /192.168.1.5:8993
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:563)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:181)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1141)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:267)
    at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.TomcatSolrRunner.configureDefaults(TomcatSolrRunner.java:151)
    at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.TomcatSolrRunner.start(TomcatSolrRunner.java:57)
    at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.SolrContainerPlugin.preSetup(SolrContainerPlugin.java:128)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.preSetup(DseDaemon.java:770)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:466)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:568)
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:91)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address (Bind failed)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:56)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:554)
    ... 10 more

Jan 30, 2017 7:52:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService addConnector
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8993]]
LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address (Bind failed) /192.168.1.5:8993
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:267)
    at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.TomcatSolrRunner.configureDefaults(TomcatSolrRunner.java:151)
    at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.TomcatSolrRunner.start(TomcatSolrRunner.java:57)
    at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.SolrContainerPlugin.preSetup(SolrContainerPlugin.java:128)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.preSetup(DseDaemon.java:770)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:466)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:568)
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:91)

Jan 30, 2017 7:52:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Solr
Jan 30, 2017 7:52:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.45
Jan 30, 2017 7:52:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory demos
Jan 30, 2017 7:52:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory solr
INFO  19:52:42,492  SolrHttpAuditLogFilter.java:219 - Initializing Solr audit logging filter
INFO  19:52:42,741  SolrDispatchFilter.java:130 - SolrDispatchFilter.init()
INFO  19:52:42,809  SolrResourceLoader.java:737 - No /solr/home in JNDI
INFO  19:52:42,810  SolrResourceLoader.java:747 - using system property solr.solr.home: solr/
INFO  19:52:42,810  SolrResourceLoader.java:136 - new SolrResourceLoader for directory: 'solr/'
INFO  19:52:43,373  SolrResourceLoader.java:737 - No /solr/home in JNDI
INFO  19:52:43,373  SolrResourceLoader.java:747 - using system property solr.solr.home: solr/
INFO  19:52:43,374  SolrResourceLoader.java:136 - new SolrResourceLoader for directory: 'solr/'
INFO  19:52:43,571  CoreContainer.java:95 - New CoreContainer 1457573163
INFO  19:52:43,698  SolrDispatchFilter.java:137 - user.dir=/Users/chandanpatra/dse
INFO  19:52:43,699  SolrDispatchFilter.java:148 - SolrDispatchFilter.init() done
INFO  19:52:43,710  RepeatablePOSTQueryFilter.java:75 - Initializing com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.RepeatablePOSTQueryFilter filter
Jan 30, 2017 7:52:43 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
SEVERE: Error starting endpoint
java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address (Bind failed) /192.168.1.5:8993
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:563)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.start(JIoEndpoint.java:579)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.start(Http11Protocol.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.TomcatSolrRunner.start(TomcatSolrRunner.java:58)
    at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.SolrContainerPlugin.preSetup(SolrContainerPlugin.java:128)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.preSetup(DseDaemon.java:770)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:466)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:568)
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:91)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address (Bind failed)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:56)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:554)
    ... 12 more

Jan 30, 2017 7:52:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
SEVERE: Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8993]]
LifecycleException:  service.getName(): "Solr";  Protocol handler start failed: java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address (Bind failed) /192.168.1.5:8993
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.TomcatSolrRunner.start(TomcatSolrRunner.java:58)
    at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.SolrContainerPlugin.preSetup(SolrContainerPlugin.java:128)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.preSetup(DseDaemon.java:770)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:466)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:568)
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:91)

Jan 30, 2017 7:52:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2554 ms
INFO  19:52:43,733  SolrContainerPlugin.java:129 - Embedded Tomcat started
INFO  19:52:43,769  SearchProtocol.java:65 - Registered SearchProtocol
INFO  19:52:43,769  SolrContainerPlugin.java:143 - Starting the legacy Netty server...
Exception (java.lang.RuntimeException) encountered during startup: java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address
    at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.SolrContainerPlugin.preSetup(SolrContainerPlugin.java:154)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.preSetup(DseDaemon.java:770)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:466)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:568)
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:91)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:485)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1094)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:428)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:414)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:897)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:198)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:349)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:358)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR 19:52:44,249  CassandraDaemon.java:709 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address
    at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.SolrContainerPlugin.preSetup(SolrContainerPlugin.java:154) ~[dse-search-5.0.5.jar:5.0.5]
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.preSetup(DseDaemon.java:770) ~[dse-core-5.0.5.jar:5.0.5]
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:466) ~[dse-core-5.0.5.jar:5.0.5]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:568) ~[cassandra-all-3.0.11.1485.jar:3.0.11.1485]
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:91) [dse-core-5.0.5.jar:5.0.5]
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125) ~[netty-all-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:485) ~[netty-all-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1094) ~[netty-all-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:428) ~[netty-all-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:414) ~[netty-all-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:897) ~[netty-all-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:198) ~[netty-all-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:349) ~[netty-all-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:358) ~[netty-all-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357) ~[netty-all-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112) ~[netty-all-4.0.34.Final.jar:4.0.34.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
INFO  19:52:44,250  DseDaemon.java:577 - DSE shutting down...
Jan 30, 2017 7:52:44 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-192.168.1.5-8993
INFO  19:52:44,251  PluginManager.java:104 - All plugins are stopped.
Exception in thread "Daemon shutdown" java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.addLocalApplicationStateInternal(Gossiper.java:1465)
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.addLocalApplicationStates(Gossiper.java:1489)
    at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.addLocalApplicationState(Gossiper.java:1479)
    at com.datastax.bdp.gms.DseState.setActiveStatusSync(DseState.java:241)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.preStop(DseDaemon.java:597)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.safeStop(DseDaemon.java:608)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.lambda$getShutdownHook$44(DseDaemon.java:927)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Jan 30, 2017 7:52:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Solr
Jan 30, 2017 7:52:45 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/solr] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 30, 2017 7:52:45 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/solr] appears to have started a thread named [NonPeriodicTasks:1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jan 30, 2017 7:52:45 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-192.168.1.5-8993
```

Thanks,
Chandan

Comment: Try `nc -l 192.168.1.5 8993` see if you're able to bind to that port on that interface.

Comment: Thanks @phact . I tried that. But was unsuccessful

Comment: So the port is probably in use by another process or the IP is not the one on the NIC. `sudo lsof -i:8993`

Answer (score 1):

please check once that the services is not already running , and the port is not being used by any other service .
I also faced the same issue and resolved by killing the service and starting again .

Comment: Did you tried to restart it . did it work or you are still facing the issue?

Comment: Yes. I tried by restarting DSE as well as the system. No luck.